# Fail to install Google Cloud CLI - 'ython' is not recognized

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I try to install Google Cloud CLI on my Windows 11 machine vy following [these](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/install) instruction.

But I get the following error.

```
Output folder: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK
Downloading Google Cloud CLI core.
Extracting Google Cloud CLI core.
Create Google Cloud CLI bat file: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\cloud_env.bat
Installing components.
Welcome to the Google Cloud CLI!
Beginning update. This process may take several minutes.
Your current Google Cloud CLI version is: 415.0.0
Installing components from version: 458.0.0
+---------------------------------------------------------+
|            These components will be updated.            |
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+
|               Name              |  Version   |   Size   |
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+
| Bundled Python 3.11             |     3.11.6 | 21.5 MiB |
| Google Cloud CLI Core Libraries | 2023.12.15 | 22.2 MiB |
| gcloud cli dependencies         | 2023.12.08 | 11.8 MiB |
+---------------------------------+------------+----------+
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|                     These components will be installed.                     |
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
|                         Name                        |  Version   |   Size   |
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
| BigQuery Command Line Tool                          |    2.0.101 |  1.6 MiB |
| BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Specific)      |    2.0.101 |  < 1 MiB |
| Cloud Storage Command Line Tool                     |       5.27 | 11.3 MiB |
| Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform Specific) |       5.27 |  < 1 MiB |
| Cloud Tools for PowerShell                          |   1.0.1.10 | 17.9 MiB |
| Google Cloud CLI Core Libraries (Platform Specific) | 2023.12.15 |  < 1 MiB |
| Google Cloud CRC32C Hash Tool                       |      1.0.0 |  1.3 MiB |
| Windows command line ssh tools                      |            |  3.3 MiB |
| anthoscli                                           |     0.2.46 | 69.5 MiB |
| gcloud cli dependencies                             | 2021.04.16 |  < 1 MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------+------------+----------+
A lot has changed since your last upgrade.  For the latest full release notes,
please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/release_notes
#============================================================#
#= Creating update staging area                             =#
#============================================================#
#= Uninstalling: Bundled Python 3.9                         =#
#============================================================#
#= Uninstalling: Google Cloud CLI Core Libraries            =#
#============================================================#
#= Uninstalling: gcloud cli dependencies                    =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool                   =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: BigQuery Command Line Tool (Platform Spec... =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Bundled Python 3.11                          =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool              =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Cloud Storage Command Line Tool (Platform... =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Cloud Tools for PowerShell                   =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Cloud Tools for PowerShell                   =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Default set of gcloud commands               =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Google Cloud CLI Core Libraries              =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Google Cloud CLI Core Libraries (Platform... =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Google Cloud CRC32C Hash Tool                =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Google Cloud CRC32C Hash Tool                =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Windows command line ssh tools               =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: Windows command line ssh tools               =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: anthoscli                                    =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: anthoscli                                    =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gcloud cli dependencies                      =#
#============================================================#
#= Installing: gcloud cli dependencies                      =#
#============================================================#
#= Creating backup and activating new installation          =#
#============================================================#
Performing post processing steps...
............................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................done.
Update done!
This will install all the core command line tools necessary for working with
the Google Cloud Platform.
For more information on how to get started, please visit:
  https://cloud.google.com/sdk/docs/quickstarts
'ython'' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
'

Failed to install.
```

I've added the path to the python in the PATH environment variable. I've validated that by successfully running python in the terminal by running the `python` command.

I've added a system variable called `CLOUDSDK_PYTHON` in my system variables containing the path to the python.exe file.

I'm using python version 3.12.1

Answer (score 3):

## EDIT

Fix is relased in version `458.0.1`

---

It seems like currently there's an issue with `gcloud` in Windows (other platforms not reported so far) as reported [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/317112914).

You may want to leave a comment there and track when it's resolved.

As well there's not workaround for now but maybe using a previous version of `gcloud` can work.

Comment: Thank you. I installed WSL and followd the install instructions for linux instead and that worked fine.

Comment: This has been fixed in version 458.0.1 released today (2023-12-20).